# css3-mediaqueries.js cross domain issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain

When using css3-mediaqueries.js for IE8 and older AND "Access data sources across domains" is not set to "disable" in settings > Security > Custom level, I get the error:

"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. do you want to continue?"

This does not affect any other browser, nor any version of IE from 9 and above.  Also, this warning will not show if "Access data sources across domains" is set to disable.  The problem is, there are people out there (including within our company) that get this warning.

If I remove:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then the warning goes away, but obviously I lose all the functionality that it offers.
I've also tried saving css3-mediaqueries.js locally, but that didn't help.

Comment: I've tried respond and mediatizr, but they dont seem to work, so I think I'm stuck with css3-media-queries.

Comment: Try adding the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).ASPX).  I can't remember everything it does, but it does solve *some* issues along this line.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I'll give it a try when I'm back in the office on Monday and report back :)

Comment: Hi Jeremy. No joy I'm afraid.  Currently my site is internal only. I'm wondering if MOTW would only work if it went to the external proxy?